# Force user to reply to the "Authorize Geolocation" input each time he try to use it

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I'm currently working on an application which use the html5 geolocation api.

I've got a button meaning 'Locate me', how try to run - or rerun - the geolocation. If the user grant the access, there is no problem, but, if he refuse it, is there a way to display the authorisation prompt again?

Thanks for your replies!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to display permissions prompt again but you can use error callback to handle [`PERMISSION_DENIED`](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#permission_denied_error) code (e.g., display further instructions for the user):

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  function(position) {
    // Success.
  },
  function(error) {
    if (error.code === error.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
      // Do Something.
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: I know how to use the fallback, that wasn't the question :-) I'm really looking for a tricks flushing the browser history! But, based on your answer, this is not possible.. I'll do with that ;) Tks for you time!